# Unsatisfied link error under Maven exec / debug plugins on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven-2, java-native-interface

I'm getting a runt-time "Unsatisfied link error" for libraries installed in Linux system library, which are definitely visible. This project works normally when I let Eclipse to manage it.

Does someone know if there any caveats regarding JNI and Maven, and can advice about this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run your code outside eclipse?

Comment: via java -jar "jarname", this works fine.

The problem happens within Eclipse/Netbeans environment.

Comment: So, if I rephrase, the problem happens when you use M2Eclipse, right?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be related to Maven itself.

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand when the problem occurs exactly. Is it during `mvn test`, during `mvn exec:exec`, does it happen on the command line, under eclipse, both? Can you clarify?

Comment: It happens during mvn exec / debug, both under Eclipse and on command line.

Comment: Please, add more details: where are the native libraries exactly, what is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, what is the content of the `java.library.path` system property when running `exec:exec`, show the relevant parts of your pom (like the maven exec plugin setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that Eclipse has remapped the value of the system property `java.library.path` for it's own purposes. This is the system property which is used to load native libraries.

I would suggest trying to tweak it by editing eclipse.ini, but if the code runs fine outside of Eclipse, why is this even a problem?

Comment: The regular run under Eclpse without MAven works normally, so this not the case.

It happens only when I use Maven to launch the app.